# cmder terminal integration into IntelliJ / WebStorm / GoLand with aliases

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, webstorm, goland, cmder

I would like to use the [cmder](https://cmder.net/) shell inside IntelliJ / GoLand / WebStorm and so on. 
Additionally, I want to use bash instead of the default cmd.

This can be achieved by changing the settings at *Settings > Tools > Terminal*:

For the Shell path, configure

```
cmd.exe /c  "path\to\my\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\bin\bash.exe"
```

This works as expected: When opening a terminal window, cmder starts bash. 
However, there is one issue with this: aliases are not working.

In a normal cmder bash-window, I can use aliases like `ll`. Here, I can't.
I found the aliases to be defined in `cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`

**Edit:** When I use the following shell path:

```
cmd.exe /c  "path\to\my\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```

... the alias works. But when opening the console, I always get the following error message:

```
Creating user startup file: /config/user_profile.sh
cp: cannot stat '/vendor/user_profile.sh.default': No such file or directory
```

Changing the "Start directory" to the cmder folder does not solve the issue.

How can I get them running inside my IDE?

Comment: Could you please check if https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/282#issuecomment-163365611 helps?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I already got my initial solution from there ;)

Comment: @CrazyCoder Anyway, I now got aliases to work (see my edited question), but now the paths are somehow wrong - see the above error message.

Comment: What command line do you use outside of the IDE to run cmder bash so that it works without errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution: you need to configure your terminal like this:

```
cmd.exe /c  ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\git-for-windows\bin\bash.exe" --login -i"
```

In addition to that, in "Environment variables", define the cmder-path:

```
CMDER_ROOT=C:\path\to\your\cmder
```

(You can also do this in the terminal settings - you don't need to set a system-wide environment variable)

If you want a different default-shell, use the exact same parameters as the cmder task you want. You can see them in cmder by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, and then going to *Startup -> Tasks*.

**Details:**

- `--login -i` is needed to load things like alias configurations
- The environment variable `CMDER_ROOT` is needed to get rid of the path error stated in the question. It's not possible to replace it with the actual path.
- Double-quotes are needed due to the environment-variable expansion

Comment: This works if you have the `git-for-windows` folder. I don't have it, so I changed the `Shell path` in `Terminal` settings to 

`"cmd.exe" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`

Answer (score 3):

**Steps**

**1.** create environment variable under Advanced System Settings, System Properties, Environment Variables, System Variables with name-value: CMDER_ROOT=C:\path\to\your\cmder

**2.** create cmder_shell.bat file in cmder folder u mentioned in step 1. with content: '@cmd.exe /k %0..\vendor\init.bat'

**3.** in shell path write: cmd.exe /c  ""%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder_shell.bat